# How to send data to Rails application using Python?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I have the following form in a rails app:

```
<form class="new_reading" id="new_reading" action="/readings" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="9pRzozPNEGGsJLJAgIXYNG8gG6nuGBsXKvqShsu99+xU/CWSXXFoEtuqzg4gTJRhbKt6P5EjQJPFsWiHdXnHOQ==" />

  <div class="field">
    <label for="reading_reading">Reading</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="reading[reading]" id="reading_reading" />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Reading" />
  </div>
</form>
```

(created using the `generate scaffold` command)

My question is: how do I populate it with data from a text file using a python (3.2.3) script?

UPDATE

Following Ativ's suggestion, I got this:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://10.42.0.1:3000/readings'
values = {'reading': 'aaa'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')

req = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data)
```

But now I get this error in webrick:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "aaa":String):
  app/controllers/readings_controller.rb:74:in `reading_params'
  app/controllers/readings_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Seems like a strange thing to do, why not just read the text file using ruby?

Comment: @Ativ, the rails app and the python script run on different devices, and I can't install ruby on the latter.

Comment: You could send the data to a controller using a Python http client, https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/http.client.html